# How to delete a input field individually using "this" with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I want to delete individual input field elements using a delete button.
I know this is simple but what am I missing?  How do you delete the input fields individually without referencing the input ID's?

```js
function del_input() {
  var el = document.querySelector(".one, .two");
  el.remove(this);
}
```

```html
<p>I want to delete them individually, but how?</p>

<div class="one two">
  <button onclick="del_input(this)">Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value one">

  <button onclick="del_input(this)">Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value two">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying actually to remove - given your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining your element inside the function, simply pass through the element as the function parameter as `del_input(el)`. This way, when you call `del_input(this)`, `el` will refer to `this` (the element you're clicking on). In this case, that's the `<button>` elements.

You'll probably also want to remove the **[`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)** to target the associated `<input>` elements, though note that this must be done **before** removing the targetted elements themselves.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function del_input(el) {
  el.nextElementSibling.remove();
  el.remove();
}
```

```html
<p>I want to delete them individually but how?</p>

<div class="one two">
  <button onclick="del_input(this)">Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value one">
  <button onclick="del_input(this)">Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value two">
</div>
```

Also note that you have duplicate IDs in your example, which is **[considered invalid markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#ref-for-concept-id%E2%91%A5)**. If you want to group your inputs, use classes instead.

Finally, you'll want to make use on unobtrusive JavaScript and turn those `onclick()` events into **[event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** by slightly changing the code:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.remove();
    this.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<p>I want to delete them individually but how?</p>

<div class="one two">
  <button>Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value one">
  <button>Delete Me</button>
  <input type="text" value="value two">
</div>
```

Keep in mind that use of `nextElementSibling` is highly dependent on your markup; if you alter the markup, you'll need to alter the selector(s).

Comment: TipOfTheDay: A simple change in HTML markup would lead to JS errors. This is not how we're supposed to do stuff. i'd sugest to properly pair using parent elements and deleting such parent instead. Also `onclick` should be better left on w3schools ifyouknowwhatimean...

Comment: (Please, for the love of the internet, show how to use unobtrusive JavaScript.)

Comment: Updated to use unobtrusive JavaScript :)

Comment: I know that the question specifically asks for use of `this` but I still feel that delegated event handling would be a better approach for this sort of task. Regardless, this does deserve upvotes for the effort.